# How to group a list of objects by the result of a function that compares two of the objects?

Tags: python

How to group a list of objects (`orgs`) by the result of a function that compares two of the objects (`is_duplicate`)?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Organisation:
    name: str
    country: str
    fetched_from: str 

orgs = [    
    Organisation(name='Facebook', country='US', fetched_from='sourceA'), # duplicate, should be detected
    Organisation(name='Google', country='GB', fetched_from='sourceA'),
    Organisation(name='Tesla', country='CH', fetched_from='sourceA'),
    Organisation(name='Amazon', country='US', fetched_from='sourceB'),
    Organisation(name='Walmart', country='DE', fetched_from='sourceB'),
    Organisation(name='Sony', country='JP', fetched_from='sourceB'),
    Organisation(name='Facebook', country='US', fetched_from='sourceB'), # duplicate, should be detected
    Organisation(name='Orlen', country='PL', fetched_from='sourceB'),
]

def is_duplicate(org1: Organisation, org2: Organisation):
    return org1.name == org2.name
```

I have looked at both `itertools.groupby` and pandas `groupby`, but their grouping function is called on single object, and my `is_duplicate' func takes two.

The resulting list of objects should look something like this:

```
grouped_by_duplicates = [
    (
        #detected Facebook duplicate
        Organisation(name='Facebook', country='US', fetched_from='sourceA'),
        Organisation(name='Facebook', country='US', fetched_from='sourceB'),
    ),
    # the rest of orgs are single element tuples, no duplicates detected
    (Organisation(name='Google', country='GB', fetched_from='sourceA')),
    (Organisation(name='Tesla', country='CH', fetched_from='sourceA')),
    (Organisation(name='Amazon', country='US', fetched_from='sourceB')),
    (Organisation(name='Walmart', country='DE', fetched_from='sourceB')),
    (Organisation(name='Sony', country='JP', fetched_from='sourceB')),
    (Organisation(name='Orlen', country='PL', fetched_from='sourceB')),
]
```

Note: organisations per source (`fetched_from`) will always be unique, the duplicates only happen accros different sources.
So maybe this can be taken into consideration to make the solution faster.

Once I have such groups, I will be able to apply `functools.reduce` on each of them to merge the duplicates by some func, let's say:

```
def merge(org1: Organisation, org2: Organisation) -> Organisation:
    new_org = Organisation(
        name=org1.name,
        country=org1.name,
        fetched_from=f'{org1.fetched_from}, {org2.fetched_from}'
    )
    return new_org
```

Comment: @azro Did they not? >"the resulting list of object should look like this"

Comment: In this case, just use `attrgetter("name")` with the existing grouping tools.

Comment: @jonsharpe Thing is I would rather use a predefined function (`is_duplicate`), as in real world more fields other than `name` are involved in comparison and I want to avoid hardcoding their names.

Comment: You don't have to hardcode it, just extract a function e.g. `fingerprint` from `is_duplicate` so the latter just becomes `return fingerprint(org1) == fingerprint(org2)` then use the former to group. In this case it's just a trivial attribute getter, but that doesn't mean it _has_ to be. Also it would be useful to give an example that actually represents the problem, otherwise people will solve it in ways that don't help you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Group

You don't a `pair` comparator, if you group by `name`, as `itertools.groupby` does, you'll get it, just keep the values, not the key (that is name)

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

result = [list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(orgs, key=attrgetter('name')), key=attrgetter('name'))]

print(result)
```

```
[
 [Organisation(name='Amazon', country='US', fetched_from='sourceB')], 
 [
    Organisation(name='Facebook', country='US', fetched_from='sourceA'), 
    Organisation(name='Facebook', country='US', fetched_from='sourceB')
 ], 
 [Organisation(name='Google', country='GB', fetched_from='sourceA')], 
 [Organisation(name='Orlen', country='PL', fetched_from='sourceB')], 
 [Organisation(name='Sony', country='JP', fetched_from='sourceB')], 
 [Organisation(name='Tesla', country='CH', fetched_from='sourceA')], 
 [Organisation(name='Walmart', country='DE', fetched_from='sourceB')]
]
```

---

#### Merge

With your merge method

```
def merge(org1: Organisation, org2: Organisation) -> Organisation:
    return Organisation(org1.name, org1.name, f'{org1.fetched_from}, {org2.fetched_from}')
```

And the previous code

```
result = [reduce(merge, v) for k, v in 
          groupby(sorted(orgs, key=attrgetter('name')), key=attrgetter('name'))]
```

```
[
    Organisation(name='Amazon', country='US', fetched_from='sourceB'), 
    Organisation(name='Facebook', country='Facebook', fetched_from='sourceA, sourceB'), 
    Organisation(name='Google', country='GB', fetched_from='sourceA'), 
    Organisation(name='Orlen', country='PL', fetched_from='sourceB'), 
    Organisation(name='Sony', country='JP', fetched_from='sourceB'), 
    Organisation(name='Tesla', country='CH', fetched_from='sourceA'), 
    Organisation(name='Walmart', country='DE', fetched_from='sourceB')
]
```

Comment: Thanks, that is cool, but in real world my `is_duplicate` function is more complicated - it is a fairly complex algorithm that looks at  various object's (db document) fields and returns a bool. That is why I wanted to group by a predefined function (`is_duplicate`), so that I do not have to hardcode field names as in your soltuion (`key=attrgetter('name')`).

Comment: @barciewicz If you could share a better version of you method, maybe I could help you more